JGD2011 and X Y Z coordinate problems with QGIS
I'm having some likely CRS/projection issues using QGIS.
I have coordinates provided in an XYZ format that's saved as a csv.
I import the CSV as a delimited text layer with a CRS of ESPG6676 JGD2011 Japan Plane Rectangular CS VIII, which I think should be correct.
I add in a google satellite xyz tile and the point shown is quite far from the actual point.
There's an occasional issue in Japan where an older datum can throw points off by a few hundred meters, and using an online tool provided by the Geospatial Authority of Japan, I tried the converted points, which had shifted things a few hundred meters, but not nearly as far as the initial offset.
Website is here:
https://vldb.gsi.go.jp/sokuchi/surveycalc/tky2jgd/main.html
However when using the lat/long values provided from that tool into Google Earth does put me in the ballpark of where the actual point should be. Then if I take those coordinates, and run them through the converter again and input those coordinates into Google Earth I get the correct location.
There's likely a simple projection/CRS problem here, but despite running through a number of different combinations I can't seem to get it properly displayed in QGIS.

I tried your coord, add them like you (blue) and with swaped X and Y (red), and answer is swaped X with Y, If you have coords in CSV file You could just add layer in QGIS with Select Field X as second Column and Field Y as first column or when you work with existing layer use swap tool Swap XY from QGIS algorytms.



I've been beating my head against this for a while. I can't believe it was as simple as being given the data with X and Y swapped.
